# cron job not running in cpanel

Tags: php, xml, cron

Cron job script  not working in cpanel server

following is the code where we are interacting with an api and gettig the xml and then validating it with our database and updating the same.Here i have pasted only the pi reading part of cron script.

```
<?php
function httpGet($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    //  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'header1: value1',
        'header2:value2'
        )); 
    $output=curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$data= httpGet("apiurl.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
//echo $xml->asXML();
foreach($xml->apiGroups->entry->value->apiListings->entry as $info){
    echo $info->value->availableVariants->entry->value->get->asXML();
}
?>
```

Please validate if any error is there in above written php cron job script,which is not running right now for us...

Comment: Do you get any error messages?  The cod eseems syntactically correct.  What is the format of the XML you are expecting to be returned?

Comment: we are putting the contents in a file after reading it from api.that also works fine when we run the above code with that manually.But when i run it as a cron job it does not run and i cant take the error log as well as its a shared hosting environment.Please guide on this....

Comment: What exactly is the command you are running from cron?

Comment: The problem got solved.the issue was timestamp.the server was in GMT timestamp.we were giving different timestamp..

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue. When I called the script from the browser, it worked. But when I used the cron job, for some reason it didn't execute.

**So the solution was to create a second script and call the first one through curl. The second script is the one I call in the cron job.**

> $curl = curl_init();
>
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://your_link_to_the_script.php');
>
> $result = curl_exec($curl);
>
> curl_close($curl);

I hope it helps.